# Entity Framework - A one-to-many relationship returns an incorrect number of records

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The "User" entity has a one-to-many relationship on the "Group Member" entity.

```
public class User
{
    #region Public properties
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<GroupMember> GroupMembers { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

```
public class GroupMember
{
    #region Public properties
    [Required]
    [Column("groupid")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("userid")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("lu_user")]
    public int LuUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("lu_date")]
    public DateTime LuDate { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

In the UserDbContext class, I set up the relationship as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<GroupMember>()
        .HasKey(x => x.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<GroupMember>()
        .HasOne(x => x.User)
        .WithMany(x => x.GroupMembers)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
}
```

When executing a query:

```
var user = _dbContext.Users
                .Include(u => u.Profiles)
                .Include(u => u.GroupMembers)
                    .ThenInclude(gm => gm.Group)
                .Where(u => u.Id == id)
                .Select(u => u)
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

The "GroupMembers" field should contain seven records. The query result is one record for the "GroupMembers" field.

I don't understand why I am not getting the correct record count for the relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GroupMember>()
    .HasKey(x => x.UserId);
```

you are telling EF that the `UserId` column of `GroupMember` table is *unique*, thus making the relationship effectively one-to-one. That's why you are getting just one record per user, even though you have collection navigation property.

Since the `GroupMember` entity looks like join entity used in many-to-many relationships (which as we know can be view as many one-to-many relationships), most likely it needs composite primary key like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GroupMember>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.GroupId, x.UserId });
```

This should be enough if you are mapping to existing database (since you are expecting multiple records from the query, hence you know the table exists and contains multiple records per user, which won't be possible if the `UserId` was unique).

But just in case you are using code first approach with migrations, make sure to create and apply new migration after doing the above change.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not create/set DBContext yourself. Do use Scaffold-Dbcontext command to generate DBContext automatically for you.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```